# How to create LinearLayout with ImageView and add it to another LinearLayout programatically

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm having troubles trying to create a LinearLayout with an ImageView inside programatically (and add this LinearLayout to another LinearLayout). The XML code that I'm tryng to recreate is this:

```
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout_morty_combinationsV"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/black"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/morty"
                            android:id="@+id/imageView1"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/black"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/morty"
                            android:id="@+id/imageView2"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
```

This is my java code

```
        LinearLayout ll_combinations = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_morty_combinationsV);
        Iterator<MortyObj> iterator = mortys.iterator();


        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            final MortyObj mortyC = iterator.next();

            LinearLayout ll_new = new LinearLayout(this);
            ll_new.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            ll_new.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            params.weight = 1f;
            ll_new.setLayoutParams(params);
            ll_new.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);


            ImageView morty_imageview = new ImageView(this);

            try {
                InputStream ims = getAssets().open("morty_images/" + mortyC.getId() + ".png");
                Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
                morty_imageview.setImageDrawable(d);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            FrameLayout.LayoutParams imgParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            morty_imageview.setLayoutParams(imgParams);


            ll_new.addView(morty_imageview);
            ll_combinations.addView(ll_new);
          }
```

This is how it should look:

[XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNJ7P.png)

And this is how It looks:

[JAVA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT4PZ.png)

I've been stuck in this for the last 2 hours.

Comment: Why you take Frame Layout remove that line. Becuase I see your xml file you should you want the image view inside the linear layout. In your program Simply add you image view inside the ll_new linear layout and ll_new inside the ll_combiations

Comment: In addition, Remove everything inside the parent layout of your XML file. Becuase you are trying to add thought the program.

Comment: Removing imgParams doesn't change anything. I added imagwview to ll_new and ll_new to ll_combinations, those are the last two lines. I also cleaned the xml before adding anything.

Comment: Why you should not use the layout inflater inside your iterator. Just create another layout for child item. Load this child layout using layout inflater. I hope you know that Layout Inflater return the view and return view add inside you parent layout programmatically.

Comment: Another layout means new XML that contents the linear layout inside the image view, load them inside your iterator as said layout inflater that returns the view, find you image to view in return view, bind the image from assets and add that return view inside the parent layout

Comment: Just found the problem. If i load a image from res/drawables I get the view I want, if i load it from assets it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, Got it. Cool you found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the problem. If i load an image from res/drawables I get the view I want, if I load it from assets it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can create a layout with something like

```
View view = (View) findViewById(R.layout.current_layout); //the layout you set in `setContentView()`
LinearLayout picLL = new LinearLayout(CurrentActivity.this);
picLL.layout(0, 0, 100, 0);
picLL.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(1000, 60));
picLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
((ViewGroup) view).addView(picLL);
```

What parameters you pass in layout() are obviously going to depend on what you want. Then you can create separate Views to add to the Layout you just created. But I highly advise reading through the docs to understand what all can be done here.

**Edit**

```
ImageView myImage = new ImageView(this);
picLL.addView(myImage);
//set attributes for myImage;
```